# Facebook App insecure content in Chrome when nothing but text on page

Tags: facebook, security, https

I have a facebook app. It was worked for quite some time. Now its not working in chrome due to insecure content. Nothing has changed on the app.

Here is the app: https://www.facebook.com/HarvestlandOrganic/app_423240211096048

It pulls from this page: https://www.harvestlandbrand.com/facebook/our_story/

Whats the deal? All my content is secure.

I tried stripping everything out of the page except main structure tags (html, head, body) and entered some text in the body to ensure that there was not an issue with insecure content. The app still would not load in chrome and in my error log it said that it could not load due to insure content.

Comment: As a quick look in the network panel of any browser developer console would have shown you, that the Google analytics script gets loaded via HTTP when your app is loaded inside Facebook …

Comment: In the app settings I change the url from to include  www. and that solved my problem.